# How can i merge two different data frames

Tags: r, dataframe, merge

I have two data frames

data frame 1

```
df1 = data.frame(city = c('New Jersey', 'New York', 'Houston'))
```

data frame 2

```
df2 = data.frame(city = c('New Jersey', 'Houston'),
                 value = c(5, 2))
```

I want exactly this:

```
New Jersey  5
NA          NA
Houston     2
```

Comment: Join the two data frames: `dplyr::full_join(df1, df2)`

Comment: Although the answer of Seth turn to fix the problem of my question, my original data that has more lines, when i use dplyr::full_join i dont get the results that i need

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
merge(df1, df2, all=TRUE) |>
  {\(.) .[match(df1$city, .$city), ]}() |>
  within(city[is.na(value)] <- NA)
#         city value
# 2 New Jersey     5
# 3       <NA>    NA
# 1    Houston     2
```

---

*Data:*

```
df1 <- structure(list(city = c("New Jersey", "New York", "Houston")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))

df2 <- structure(list(city = c("New Jersey", "Houston"), value = c(5, 
2)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try alternatively the below code

```r
df3 <- merge(df1, df2, by='city', all.x = TRUE)

df3$city <- ifelse(is.na(df3$value), NA, df3$city)
```

<sup>Created on 2023-09-23 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

```r
        city value
1    Houston     2
2 New Jersey     5
3       <NA>    NA
```

Comment: This is not _exactly_ what OP shows he wants to have.